# Oracle: How to get all possible constraint violations?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to know if data exists in the db that would get a constraint violation for all disabled constraints. (if the constraints were enabled)

I get all disabled constraints like this:

```
select * from all_constraints where STATUS='DISABLED';
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple solution for me:

```
spool 'disabled_constraint_violations.txt';
set serverout on size unlimited
DECLARE
    sql_enable varchar2(400);
    sql_disable varchar2(400);
BEGIN
   FOR c IN (select OWNER, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME from all_constraints  where STATUS='DISABLED') LOOP
        BEGIN
        sql_enable := ' alter table ' ||  c.owner||'.'||c.table_name || ' enable constraint ' || c.constraint_name;
        execute immediate  sql_enable ;
        sql_disable := ' alter table ' ||  c.owner||'.'||c.table_name || ' disable constraint ' || c.constraint_name;
        execute immediate  sql_disable ;
        EXCEPTION   
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('table: '||c.table_name||'    ||    constraint:  '||c.constraint_name||'    ||    error message:  '||sqlerrm);
        END;
   END LOOP;
END;
set serveroutput off
spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable disabled constraints one by one. Once they fail, check which data prevents them to be enabled.

By the way, what's the use of *disabled constraints*? If data should be constrained, enable them. If not, why would you care?

Comment: It's about thousands of constraints.
The database should be moved and this information should be recorded.

Comment: Well, you could write some code to do that for you (loop through disabled constraints / enable them / record if it fails) and then investigate only *failed* ones. Is there a way to automate the *whole* process (including data that violates those constraints)? I don't think so.

Comment: I use disabled constraints to run automatic updates from "natural" foreign key to surrogate foreign key. The foreign key constraint on natural key is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use PL/SQL and the `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ENABLE CONSTRAINT EXCEPTION INTO` feature to collect the data about constraint violations.

### Sample Schema

Create two tables with disabled constraints. One has good data, the other has bad data and will fail validation:

```
drop table good_data;
drop table bad_data;

create table good_data(a number, constraint good_data_uq unique(a) disable novalidate);
insert into good_data values(1);

create table bad_data(a number, constraint bad_data_uq unique(a) disable novalidate);
insert into bad_data values(1);
insert into bad_data values(1);

commit;
```

### Enable All Disabled Constraints

The `EXCEPTION INTO` clause requires a table of a certain shape to store results. There's no package to help build the table, you have to call a script on the server like this:

```
SQL> @?\rdbms\admin\utlexpt1

Table created.
```

This PL/SQL block loops through all disabled constraints and attempts to enable them:

```
declare
    v_sql varchar2(32767);
    v_cannot_validate exception;
    pragma exception_init(v_cannot_validate, -2299);
begin
    --Remove previous exceptions.
    delete from exceptions;
    commit;

    --Enable all disabled constraints.
    --Ignore errors, but log all exceptions for later analysis.
    for constraints in
    (
        select owner, constraint_name, table_name
        from all_constraints
        where status = 'DISABLED'
            and owner = user
            and table_name not like 'BIN$%'
        order by owner, constraint_name
    ) loop
        v_sql :=
            'alter table '||constraints.owner||'.'||constraints.table_name||
            ' enable constraint '||constraints.constraint_name||
            ' exceptions into exceptions';

        begin
            execute immediate v_sql;
        exception
            when v_cannot_validate then null;
            when others then
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error with this SQL: '||
                    v_sql||chr(10)||sqlcode||sqlerrm);
        end;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

### View Exceptions

```
--Bad data summary:
select * from exceptions;

ROW_ID              OWNER    TABLE_NAME  CONSTRAINT
------              -----    ----------  ----------
AAASoBAALAAAAvWAAA  JHELLER  BAD_DATA    BAD_DATA_UQ
AAASoBAALAAAAvWAAB  JHELLER  BAD_DATA    BAD_DATA_UQ

--View bad data:
select * from bad_data where rowid in ('AAASoBAALAAAAvWAAA', 'AAASoBAALAAAAvWAAB');
```